# hello, im getting this error code when i try to load a dataset into BigQuery "Unexpected token g in JSON at position 25"

Tags: json

```
[
  {
    "description": glide_no"",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "glide_no",
    "type": "INTEGER"
  },
  {
    "description": "vehicle registration number",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "vehicle",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "description": "PSP CODE",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "client",
    "type": "STRING"
},

 {
    "description": "Company name",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "haulier",
    "type": "STRING"  /*this is position 25/*
},
 {
    "description": "waste type",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "waste_type",
    "type": "STRING"
},
 {
    "description": "source of waste",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "source",
    "type": "STRING"
},
 {
    "description": "gross weight in kg",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "gross_weight",
    "type": "INTEGER"
},
 {
    "description": "tare weight in kg",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "tare_weight",
    "type": "INTEGER"
},
 {
    "description": "net weight in kg",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "net_weight",
    "type": "INTEGER"
},
 {
    "description": "gross date",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "gross_date",
    "type": "DATETIME"
},
 {
    "description": "tare date",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "tare_date",
    "type": "DATETIME"
},
 {
    "description": "day of the week",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "day",
    "type": "STRING"
},
 {
    "description": "month of the year",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "month",
    "type": "STRING"
},
 {
    "description": "vehicle condition rating",
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "memo",
    "type": "STRING"
},
 {
    "description": "vehicle type",
    "mode": "REQUIRED",
    "name": "vehicle_type",
    "type": "STRING"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you please format this so it's easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

The first field contains invalid JSON:

```
"description": glide_no"",
```

Perhaps:

```
"description": "glide_no",
```

> **NOTE** `position 25` refers to the 25th character not line.

There are many good online tools available that help manage JSON, e.g. [The JSON Validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Thank you for the correction, and the JSON Validator